# Reading file with istream

Tags: c++, polymorphism, istream

I am working on a project which involves polymorphism and inheritance.

lets assume that the hierarchy of the classes used in the project are:

```
Media ----> Book ----> MediaRegistry
```

and the declaration of each class are as follows: (the classes have been narrowed down to the members which I have problem)

```
class Media
{
public:
    Media();
    Media(int id, string content);  
    virtual void input(istream& in) = 0;
    friend istream& operator>>(istream& in, Media& media);

protected:                          
    string _mediaTitle;
    int _id;
};
```

with:

```
istream& operator>>(istream& in, Media& media) 
{
    media.input(in);
    return in;
}
```

and:

```
class Book:public Media     // Inherits from abstract base class Media
{
public:
    Book();
    Book(int id, string title, int nrOfPages); // Constructor 
    void input(istream& in);

private:
    int _nrOfPages;
};
```

with:

```
void Book::input(istream& in)
{
    in >> _id >> _mediaTitle >> _nrOfPages;
}
```

and:

```
class MediaRegistry
{
public:
    MediaRegistry();
    int addMedia(Media*);       
    int loadMedia();

private:
    static const int MAX = 10;
    //Media* _pMedias[MAX];     // Vector for MAX numbers of Media pointers
    std::vector<Media*> _pMedias;
    int _nrOfMedias;                // _nrOfMedias == MAX when registry is full
    ifstream inFile;
    ofstream outFile;
    string path = ".\\data.txt";
};
```

with:

```
int MediaRegistry::loadMedia()
{
    inFile.open(path.c_str());
    while (!inFile.eof())
    {
        int mediaType = 0;
        inFile >> mediaType;
        if (inFile.eof())
            break;
        Media* media = nullptr;
        media = new Book();
        inFile >> *media;
        addMedia(media);
     }
    inFile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Now in the `data.txt`, as title of the media, if I have space between the words (i.e, "The Clown" in stead of e.g "the-Clown"), the program encounters a problem in this member function `istream& operator>>(istream& in, Media& media)`. I cannot understand, however, I debugged it many times to track the problem. In fact, I want my program could be able to get a string with space in it, but it doesn't do that now??

Comment: `in >> str` only reads a single word (without any whitespace) from `in` into `str`. Thus it only reads `"The"` into `str` when it tries to parse a book with whitespace in its title. If you want to read an entire line (including any whitespace), you should use [`getline(in, str)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) instead.

Comment: As I showed it in my code snippet, the problem is that for accessing the book, I have a `Media * media` and I cannot treat that as a '\0'  string

Comment: What's the exact error message or unexpected behaviour you encounter in your program?

Comment: *"the program encounters a problem in this member function..."* - What's the problem?

Comment: Also, `Book::input` reads into an integer first so how can `"the-Clown"` be read at all when there's no integer there to read?

Comment: @0x499602D2 I think he meant that "the-Clown" would come after some integer, not that it would be the entire input. However, I do agree that the format of the input could be clarified a bit.

Comment: @Manp your problem lays in the use of the extraction operator of `std::istream` for `std::string`. It delimits on whitespace or EOF. This means `"The"` is read, leaving `" Clown"` on the stream, and subsequently failing on any non-string extraction. Can you post a *real* sample of your input file (2+ entries please)? I'm betting a proper delimiter and use of `std::getline` will solve this for you. There are plenty of other things that can be better as well, but first things first.

Comment: What does `addMedia()` do?

Comment: @0x499602D2  I reads an integer first which will be taken as Media::_id and then a string will is supposed to be taken as Media::_mediaTitle and then an integer which doesn't go to Media class as one of its member variable...

Comment: @Frxstrem The problem is that: when it goes to media.input(in); in the istream& operator>>(istream& in, Media& media) of Media class it calls break as: Unhandled exception at 0x003BAB37 in MediaRegistry.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

Comment: @0x499602D2 addMedia put the extracted content as the input into a vector and treat it as the working memory of the registry

Answer (score 1):

The `>>` input operator on strings will read exactly one word (if possible) or read nothing at all. So when you have the code:

```
void Book::input(istream& in)
{
    in >> _id >> _mediaTitle >> _nrOfPages;
}
```

It expects exactly one integer, then one word and then one integer again. If you then try to give it the following input:

> 1234
>   The Clown
>   216

It will first read the integer `1234`, then the word `The` and then it will try to interpret `Clown` as an integer (which will fail). Notice how the last `216` is left unread. The next input operation on the stream will start here, which may lead to unexpected results.

If you have your file set up with a clear line structure (e.g., each "field" on a separate line), something like [`std::getline(in, line)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) would probably work better:

```
#include <iostream>     // std::istream
#include <string>       // std::getline
#include <limits>       // std::numeric_limits
using namespace std;

void Book::input(istream& in)
{
    in >> _id;
    // this ignores the rest of the line after the previously read integer
    //  (otherwise getline will just read the rest of the line)
    in.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');

    getline(in, _mediaTitle);

    in >> _nrOfPages;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [@Frxstrem's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25100041/701092) your `loadMedia()` function could use a touchup. There are a few things that it does wrong or poorly:

> 1) Opens the file stream when it can be done in the *member initializer-list* of the constructor.

`loadMedia()` should be for reading the data from the input file to the program, not for performing opening and close operations. That can be done using RAII, or the concept of initializing in the constructor and releasing in the destructor. Since the file name is already known, we can just initialize it through the member initializer-list.

```c++
MediaRegisty::MediaRegistry() : inFile{path} { }
```

Because your're using C++11 (as evidenced by your use of `nullptr`), we can use `std::ifstream`'s constructor that takes an `std::string` as an argument. I also used the *uniform initialization* syntax (`T{}`). Some compilers don't support that syntax so if you get an error just replace them with parentheses.

> 2) Performs extractions without reliably checking for failure.

`!eof()` was never meant to be used as a condition for input. The input should be done before control passes through the loop in order to minimize the possibility of using the result of a failed extraction (and thus avoid Undefined Behavior). Input streams have a boolean operator that check for stream validity. If you use it the right way it will be invoked *after* the extraction:

```c++
for (auto p = std::make_pair(int{}, make_unique<Book>());
     inFile >> p.first >> *p.second; addMedia(media));
```

I used a `std::pair` to contain the two variables and a `for` loop to put the statements that we want to execute. `make_unique<Book>()` creates a `std::unique_ptr<Book>`. `int{}` is the same as `0`.

> 3) Allocates data dynamically without releasing it, effectively causing a memory leak.

Every instance of `new`/`new[]` needs a corresponding `delete`/`delete[]`. If you don't deallocate the resource you get a memory leak.

If you ever come into a situation where you need to use dynamic allocation, please consider using memory management containers like [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) and [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr). These classes leverage the use of RAII by containing the resource and deallocating it in their destructors (when the objects go out of scope).

> 4) Closing the file unnecessarily.

File streams close their file handles when they go out of scope by calling `close()` inside their destructors. Call `close()` only when you need to reopen with a different file.

I hoped this helped. These are the changes I've made:

```c++
template<class T, class... Args>
std::unique_ptr<T> make_unique(Args&&... args) noexcept
{
    return new T{std::forward<Args>(args)...};
}

class MediaRegistry
{
public:
    MediaRegistry();
    int addMedia(std::unique_ptr<Media>);       
    int loadMedia();

private:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Media>> _pMedias;
    std::ifstream inFile;
    ...
};

MediaRegistry::MediaRegistry() : inFile{path} { }

int MediaRegistry::addMedia(std::unique_ptr<Media> p)
{
    _pMedias.push_back(std::move(p));
    return 0; // not clear what's supposed to be returned here so I put 0
}

int MediaRegistry::loadMedia()
{
    for (auto p = std::make_pair(int{}, make_unique<Book>());
         inFile >> p.first >> *p.second; addMedia(p.second));
    return 0;
}
```